# Manage family macOS logins

Tags: macos, password, login, sharing

I have a family with many macOS devices.  Originally I set these up with an admin user with the same username and password on all devices, and I used this to admin parental controls on them.

This has become an issue when the shared password was compromised.

Ideally the admin password on all family devices would have a managed password, and I could change the login password on all devices from one place.

Is it possible to achieve this functionality somehow?  Perhaps there's a iCloud Family feature I'm missing?

Comment: ICloud features and whatever Apple Family account features are well documented (I presume). What do these say?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you've discovered the perils of having a single password for multiple devices/accounts. This would be no different than if it were an IT Manager who used the same firmware PIN and admin credentials across all school computers (I say that, because I inherited that exact problem).

Apple ID doesn't haven anything to manage this and "corporate" style solutions like network authentication or mobile device management is simply overkill for what you need to do.  So, the solution is to use a different password for the admin account for each Mac and store them in a good password manager.

I use [KeepassXC](https://keepassxc.org/) for this purpose.  My personal stuff (like bank accounts and website logins) is stored on a different service, but passwords for my "infrastructure" is stored here.  All my routers, switches, servers, etc. are stored in KeePass.  KeePass is secure.  If you lose the master password, you're not getting into to it - ask me how I know.

By having a tool to manage your passwords and using different credentials for each device, any "breach" is contained and you don't compromise the rest.

Comment: I personally do use a password manager, however, not all the people who need to admin the computers are willing to.  And the password was weak partially because it needed to be memorable.    

Feels like a catch-22, right now. :/

Comment: I know the feeling...if it was work, you'd probably have more leverage, but with Family....

Comment: Well you *can* add things manually to your keychain, you could store them there as long as **your** password is not known by anyone else. It's not ideal, but...